# Docker: MySQL-Socket created with wrong permissions when bind-mounted from host to container

Tags: mysql, linux, macos, docker

I'm running Docker version 1.8.2 on MAC OS.

I try to setup a container with the webserver and the project files reside on the host (-v, bind-mount) which works. The (php) project needs database access and I tried to give it access to my host MySQL via mysql.sock socket.

I configured the host MySQL socket file location within my Users home directory that is automatically shared with the VM (the MAC OS specialty).

Then I run it with:

```
docker run -d -P -p 8000:80 \
    -v /Users/myuser/dev/myproject:/var/www/html \
    -v ~/tmp/mysql.sock:/tmp/mysql.sock:ro myimage
```

This works, but the socket

```
$ docker exec -it 7e8b1ae04acd bash
root@7e8b1ae04acd:/# ls -als /tmp
total 8
4 drwxrwxrwt  2 root root  4096 Oct  9 06:29 .
4 drwxr-xr-x 38 root root  4096 Oct  9 06:50 ..
0 -rwxrwxrwx  1 1000 staff    0 Oct  8 15:18 mysql.sock
root@7e8b1ae04acd:/#
```

is no socket anymore.

On the host the permissions are

```
0 srwxrwxrwx    1 myuser  staff      0  8 Okt 17:18 mysql.sock
```

What's possibly going wrong?